# Isomorphism from Adjoining Root of Minimal Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L$ be a field extension of $K$, and let $m_{\theta}(x)\in K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\theta\in L$. How can we show that $K[\theta]\cong K[x]/m_{\theta}(x)$?

I couldn't help but notice the similarity between this problem and that of showing $Z[i]\cong Z[x]/(x^2+1)$, but in either case I'm not sure how to construct a homomorphism between the sets, after which we need to show said homomorphism is both surjective and injective. Any help is appreciated! If someone could give as elementary a solution as possible, that will be great!

Comment: Define a map $K[x] \to K[\theta]$ by sending $x \to \theta$. Now use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Instead of the first isomorphism theorem can we construct an explicit homomorphism taking $K[\theta]\to K[x]/m_{\theta}(x)$, and instead of finding its kernel, show that it is surjective and injective?

Comment: Yes, just send $\theta$ to $\overline{x} \in K[x]/m_{\theta}(x)$. For bijectivity, you need to keep using the fact that $m_{\theta}$ is the minimal polynomial. This is a lot more work than just invoking first isomorphism.

Comment: I still don't understand how to define the explicit homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The comment is confusing at best. What he means is define
$$K[x] \to K[\alpha]\quad f(x) \mapsto f(\alpha) $$
This is easily verified to be a surjective homomorphism of rings whose kernel is precisely the ideal generated by $m_\alpha$, so the first isomorphism theorem provides the desired isomorphism.

EDIT: oh, I'm a necromancer.